# How to monitor and alert a table row value in SQL Server for a maximum value

Tags: sql-server, monitoring, jobs, sql-job

I have two rows in one table. One has the start value of an ID#1 with 100000 and the other with an ID#2 1000000

Is there any possibility to monitor and trigger an alert on Microsoft SQL Server if the values were reaching for ID#1 999999 or for ID#2 9999999?

The ID get updated by an external code. Here I need to monitor the records and notify once condition occurred. I wonder if it is possible to achieve the task from database server side?

I already searched in MS SQL MMS and on the MS SQL Documentation but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Do you really need to monitor these values or is it just an example to see how it would be done? IDs should be able to vary their digit counts and be capped in an extremely high value, like the max value for an integer data type. Also if there's an action you will have to do once these values arrive, you want to make sure to know a couple thousand before they arrive (depending on the amount generated per day), so you would get notified at 9.999.000.

Comment: That's a good point. You're right, I should install some threshold reach some reaction time. The critical value should never been reached, but it has to be a certain length, because the IDs are valeted by length in the external program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up a recurring SQL job in the SQL Job Agent that checks for the existence of a record and sends you an e-mail if it's there.

```
 IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM   tablea
           WHERE  id >= 999999)
  EXEC Sp_send_dbmail; -- this needs to be expanded of course

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM   tableb
           WHERE  id >= 999999)
  EXEC Sp_send_dbmail;
```